# Understanding tally(sort = TRUE)

Tags: r, dplyr

So there was this code before:

```
flights %>%
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(arr_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE),
  n = n()) %>%
arrange(desc(arr_delay))
```

This code I understand. However this code right below that one shows:

```
flights %>%
  group_by(carrier, flight, dest) %>%
  tally(sort = TRUE) %>% # Save some typing
  filter( n == 365)
```

So this code I don't get the

```
tally(sort = TRUE)
```

When it said save some typing, what exactly is it saving? I understand that the `tally(sort = TRUE)` replaces `summerise(n = n())`, but how does it "save typing" and how does it relate to each other? If anyone can give me a break down of `tally(sort = TRUE)` that'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "save typing" to me means it saves some typing from having to type the `summarise` (and subsequent) line. No?  Also, there's a help file for `tally`

Comment: Is that the only thing it saves? that it saves typing summarise? I just want to make sure there's no other application for the operator "tally"

Comment: Where did you get this code? Is it from Hadley's useR! tutorial?

Comment: ^Yes! Learning R is hard.. :(

Comment: I agree it's a challenge.  I would recommend you get the data, fiddle around with stuff, change arguments, try things out, etc.  And most of all, have patience.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm far from being a `dplyr` expert, but since no one wants to answer, I'll give it a shot. So from [tally documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/node/230679) all it does is just giving you the frequencies per group. If you embed two `tally`s, they will just `sum` the frequencies, so for example:

```
library(dplyr)
tally(group_by(CO2, Plant)) 

#    Plant n
# 1    Qn1 7
# 2    Qn2 7
# 3    Qn3 7
# 4    Qc1 7
# 5    Qc3 7
# 6    Qc2 7
# 7    Mn3 7
# 8    Mn2 7
# 9    Mn1 7
# 10   Mc2 7
# 11   Mc3 7
# 12   Mc1 7
```

is just base R `table`

```
table(CO2$Plant)
# Qn1 Qn2 Qn3 Qc1 Qc3 Qc2 Mn3 Mn2 Mn1 Mc2 Mc3 Mc1 
#   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
```

and

```
tally(tally(group_by(CO2, Plant)))
#    n
# 1 84
```

is just

```
sum(table(CO2$Plant))
# [1] 84
```

or

```
tally(CO2)
#   n
#1 84
```

or

```
nrow(CO2)
# [1] 84
```

So re your question,

```
flights %>%
  group_by(carrier, flight, dest) %>%
  tally(sort = TRUE) %>% # Save some typing
  filter( n == 365)
```

means

```
Take data set "flights" 
 group it by "carrier", "flight" and "dest" columns
 give me the frequencies of these combinations and sort them by frequecy
 return only the combinations that their frequency equals to 365
```